# weppack output.publicPath

Tags: javascript, webpack

Имею такую настройку в конфиге webpack:

```
output: {
  filename: 'assets/js/[name].js',
  chunkFilename: 'assets/js/[name].js',
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  publicPath:  '/'
```

},

Все складывается куда нужно, однако при загрузке чанка получаю ошибку:

> GET http://localhost:3000/assets/js/3.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Оно и понятно, сервер настроен так, что доступ есть только внутрь каталога `assets`, т.е. `assets` и есть корень сайта откуда берутся статические файлы.
Как сделать так, что-бы вебпак ложил чанки в `app/assets/js`, но при этом они были доступны по `/js/file.js`
пробовал задавать для `publicPath` функцию типа `publicPath: url => '/' + url.slice(url.indexOf('/') + 1)`, однако `url` - это не строка пути - это некий хеш.
В общем нужна помощь в решении проблемы.

Comment: Убрать assets из filename и добавить в path?

Comment: @Alexey Ten да спасибо, так и сделал, сначала задал вопрос, а потом дошло, что path нужно задать с assets сразу.